# raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause)) urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=49426):

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am writing a bot that must execute scripts at a specific time. The first script runs well, but the second doesn't want to. Throws this error urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=50039): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/ff59b4e8d80282f58c766e631996b3b3/window (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001DDDCEDF1C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061].

My code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import schedule

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=./chromeprofile")
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
# options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Ilya\PycharmProjects\University_BOT\Chrome\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
url = 'https://meet.google.com/lookup/gy7njx5dia?authuser=1&hs=179'

''' first_second_lesson_monday
first - Номер тижня
second - пара по счоту

'''

first_monday = {
    'IT' :  'https://meet.google.com/urb-rjsp-wqm',
    'Urkaine_Language': 'https://meet.google.com/lookup/axjfog62dw?authuser=1&hs=179'
}


def second_first_lesson_wednesday():
    try:
        driver.get(url = 'https://meet.google.com/urb-rjsp-wqm' )
        time.sleep(3)
        off_micro = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="U26fgb JRY2Pb mUbCce kpROve uJNmj QmxbVb HNeRed"]').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        off_cam = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="DPvwYc JnDFsc dMzo5"]')
        off_cam[1].click()
        time.sleep(4)
        press_coninue = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="NPEfkd RveJvd snByac"]').click()
        time.sleep(60)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
schedule.every().day.at("13:28").do(second_first_lesson_wednesday)




def second_second_lesson_wednesday():
    try:
        driver.get(url= 'https://meet.google.com/lookup/hvug6sxjey?authuser=1&hs=179')
        time.sleep(3)
        off_micro = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="U26fgb JRY2Pb mUbCce kpROve uJNmj QmxbVb HNeRed"]').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        off_cam = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="DPvwYc JnDFsc dMzo5"]')
        off_cam[1].click()
        time.sleep(4)
        press_coninue = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="NPEfkd RveJvd snByac"]').click()
        time.sleep(40)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()
schedule.every().day.at("14:35").do(second_second_lesson_wednesday)

def second_third_lesson_wednesday():
    try:
        driver.get(url='https://meet.google.com/lookup/e6kettrs2b?authuser=1&hs=179')
        time.sleep(3)
        off_micro = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="U26fgb JRY2Pb mUbCce kpROve uJNmj QmxbVb HNeRed"]').click()
        time.sleep(4)
        off_cam = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="DPvwYc JnDFsc dMzo5"]')
        off_cam[1].click()
        time.sleep(4)
        press_coninue = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="NPEfkd RveJvd snByac"]').click()
        time.sleep(30)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()


schedule.every().day.at("14:39").do(second_third_lesson_wednesday)


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the error you're facing means that the script can't access the url. This could be because of an SSL certificate, google meet doesn't support bots, or some other reason relating to your network. Most likely because of the timeout like in this [thread](https://dev-qa.com/594819/selenium-max-retries-exceeded-with-url-how-to-treat) I would suggest using webbot instead of selenium as it's more versatile or using the suggestions in the other thread.